# Can we add some related sites for question migration, so people can vote?

Tags: discussion, moderation, close-reasons

Currently our Off-Topic Migration site is empty (exempt meta site), so this option is not used.

[image]

Can we add the common related sites, for example:

- [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/)
- [Fitness.SE](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/)
- [Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)

So people can vote in order to migrate into these sites?

Comment: We certainly need these, but I'm not sure a site can get them before graduation.

Answer (score 5):

While I do like this idea, [beta sites don't get migration paths](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60409/284141). There is special case in which [Writers SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com) has a migration path to [ELU SE](http://english.stackexchange.com). Right now, I don't think we could even be one of those special cases, though, because we are still a relatively young site and we need more time to fully figure out our scope.

Moderators can migrate to other sites, though, so if you do see a question that should be on another site, please flag for moderation attention and say that it should be migrated to another site.